# Submitting the value of a disabled input field

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable an input field, but when I submit the form it should still pass the value.

Use case: I am trying to get latitude and longitude from Google Maps and wanna display it, but I don't want the user to edit it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 302, accepted):

> I wanna Disable an Input Field on a
>   form and when i submit the form the
>   values from the **disabled form is not
>   submitted**.
>
> Use Case: i am trying to get Lat Lng
>   from Google Map and wanna Display it..
>   **but dont want the user to edit it**.

You can use the `readonly` property in your input field

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: Note that the input will still be able to receive focus. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443952/remove-text-caret-pointer-from-focused-readonly-input

Comment: Great answer 8 years later.  Just wanted to add that to make the text appear un-editable I add the css: `input:read-only { color:grey; }`

Comment: Wow, 10 years later here i am. Struggeling with the disabled.
readonly="readonly" is the solution. Thanks alot

Comment: you can just use `readonly` instead of `readonly="readonly" `

Comment: This doesn't work on checkboxes and radio-buttons, unfortunately - as they cannot be marked `readonly`.

Answer (score 27):

I know this is old but I just ran into this problem and none of the answers are suitable. nickf's solution works but it requires javascript. The best way is to disable the field and still pass the value is to use a hidden input field to pass the value to the form. For example,

```
<input type="text" value="22.2222" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="hidden" name="lat" value="22.2222" />
```

This way the value is passed but the user sees the greyed out field. The readonly attribute does not gray it out.

Comment: You could add CSS on the disabled text boxes to gray them out.

Comment: Is the `value` necessary in disabled input?

Comment: Yes it is necessary to display the value

Answer (score 14):

you can also use the Readonly attribute: the input is not gonna be grayed but it won't be editable

```
<input type="text" name="lat" value="22.2222" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Input elements have a property called `disabled`. When the form submits, just run some code like this:

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
myInput.disabled = true;
```

Comment: Addressing the original question, in order to pass the value during the form submission "disabled" property should be "false" instead of "true".