# Cursor blinking even though field is readonly

Tags: html, css, focus

I made a field readonly but when I click at the field I see a cursor blinking. Is it possible that the cursor should blink when the value is readonly?

```
<input type='text' name='fname' value="100000" readonly="true"  />
```

Comment: maybe you need disabled instead of readonly. http://kreotekdev.wordpress.com/2007/11/08/disabled-vs-readonly-form-fields/

Comment: Related: [Remove text caret/pointer from focused readonly input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5443952)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readonly="readonly"` is what you should be using.

Comment: in fact, the value of the attribute makes no difference at all, except in the context of xhtml, in which case is *must* be `readonly="readonly"` as you say in order for the code to be valid xhtml. But even then it's the DTD validator that would complain, not the browser; all browsers will work with any value for the `readonly` attribute, or even no value at all.

Comment: @Wesley - in terms of the absolute correct syntax, yes, it should be either `readonly="readonly"` or simply `readonly`. What I was pointing out is that browsers don't care about this and will work exactly the same with `readonly="true"`. And thus while this answer is pointing out the correct syntax, it won't actually make any difference to the OP, and more importantly, it won't solve their problem.

Comment: @Spudley: The link was for Chrono (or anyone else interested), not you specifically. `readonly="hell-yeah"` will work, I know :)

Comment: @Wesley - hehe. yeah, I worked that out after I posted the comment. But I think it was good to clarify my point anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The `readonly` attribute does not change how the field is rendered -- you will indeed still see a blinking cursor. But if you try to type into the field, you will find it doesn't respond.

If you want it to look different, you need to use CSS to style the field when it is disabled. For example:

```
.myfield[disabled] {
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

...to make the field light grey when it is disabled.

But as far as I know, there is no way to change the blinking cursor in a text field; certainly not to stop it blinking.

If you want to not have a cursor in the field at all, you could use the `disabled` attribute instead of `readonly`. But this has other side effects as well, and works quite differently to `readonly`.

Comment: On the post I linked to in the comments (my own), some people said they did *not* see a blinking caret on a readonly input, I think it might depend on browser and/or OS. Of course, it should only appear on focus, so `onfocus="this.blur()"` was the hacky workaround I used.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in IE 11/Mozilla Fire Fox or other versions.

I resolved this issue using JQuery by adding the following:

```
Line 1      $('#Id').prop('readonly', true);       
Line 2      $('#Id').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

use  `<span> 10000 </span>` tag.U may got your solution.