# How to remove caret from text box?

Tags: html

Here is my code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="test1" readonly  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="test2"  readonly /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" value="test3" readonly /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How do I remove the caret from the text box?

Comment: I don't want to disable the text box. I just want it to make readonly and the cursor will not blinking

Comment: If you don't mind using javascript and not being able to focus the element, try `onfocus="this.blur()"`. Related question: [Remove text caret/pointer from focused readonly input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443952/5444007#5444007)

Comment: Are you talking about hiding the **cursor** (thing that moves with the mouse) or **caret** (blinking vertical line that usually appears when you type)?

Answer (score 7):

If the browser shows the insertion caret when the [`readonly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#readonly) attribute is set on an [`input[type="text"]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) element, you may be able to use the [`caret-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color) CSS property to make the caret [`transparent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#transparent_keyword):

```css
.caret-hidden {
  caret-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<input class="caret-hidden" type="text" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1):

Poor man's solution: transmit value in a hidden form item (`<input type="hidden">`) and display it in a regular HTML container (`<p></p>`, `<div></div>` or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

The mouse cursor has several CSS values.
To remove the cursor from the textbox you can use the following

```
<input type="text" value="test2" style="cursor:none" readonly />
```

By setting it to none, the cursor will not be displayed. But you can also choose to use other styles like `cursor:zoom-in`. `cursor: default` etc.
For more CSS cursor values, take a look at the MDN documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean this :

```
<input type="text" name="site" value="Stackoverflow" readonly="readonly" />
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/UuZnh/

Comment: `readonly` is a [boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2), so it does not require a value. `<input type="text" readonly>` is not wrong.

Comment: @Wesley Regardless of what is technically accurate, this actually works. Behavior is not the same (see the demo). So kudos to Stack.

Comment: @evan: I still get the caret in FF5 on Win7, and I don't see any difference between this and OP's code: http://jsfiddle.net/UuZnh/3/ Which OS/browser are you seeing a difference in?

Comment: @Wesley - Interesting... It does work in Chrome, but then so does the OP's code.