# how to disable focus textbox in html?

Tags: html

when I click in textbox html, have a focus (|). I want to remove "|" from textbox, no disable textbox because i want to catch keyup event

Comment: Um... why? Do you want input, or don't you?

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Don't change things like this, it serves no purpose other than to confuse your users.

Comment: I just want to remove signal "|" in textbox, not disable, because I make treeview and I use textbox to display text, when I click in textbox, the "|" appear

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6884972/1563422

Comment: "I make treeview and I use textbox to display text" - The standard paradigm in a tree view is to switch between text nodes and editable nodes, not to have dozens (hundreds?) of inputs waiting to be edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to remove the cursor from a textbox and for a good reason. However, There might be a valid case where you would like to catch key events for something like a game and not show the cursor. In this case, you could use something like a div and catch the keydown/keyup event.

Here is an example:

```
<div onkeyup="alert('hi')" tabindex="1" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
```