# ASP.NET Entity Framework Disabled textfield gets updated as empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using ASP.NET Entity Framework and I have this text field, which is disabled:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.consultant, new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
```

I have this on the Edit page, but when I goto save it, it updates consultant column as an empty string.

Here is the method code:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,consultant,image,message,startStop")] SetupClass setupClass)
        {
            string[] username = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\');

            ViewBag.User = username[0];

            ViewBag.Renderings = dbRendering.Data.OrderBy(m => m.order).ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(setupClass).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Message = "Updated";
                return View(setupClass);
            }
            return View(setupClass);
        }
```

I guess I could exclude the consultant column from the method as I don't need to update it at all.

Comment: Well, if it's disabled then it probably isn't sending a value to the server.  Check the runtime values on `setupClass`.  If it's empty, then that would be why it's saving as empty.  Perhaps you instead want to include the field?  Why is it disabled in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submitting the value of a disabled input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045648/submitting-the-value-of-a-disabled-input-field)